# StreamWriter doesn't create a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have writtten a code to Create & write a file.But It doen't create a file.There's no any compilation error.My folder hierachy is DesktopModules -> SMSFunction->SMSText.I need to create a text file inside the SMSText folder,

```
public void WriteToFile(  string source, int dest, string messageIn, string operatorNew)
{
    try{

    string directory = ResolveUrl("~/DesktopModules/SMSFunction/SMSText");
    //string directory = Server.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/SMSFunction/SMSText");
    string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}.txt", DateTime.Now);
    string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);

    if (!File.Exists(filename))
    {

        using (StreamWriter str = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);
            str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);
            str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);
            str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);
            str.Flush();

        }
    }
    else if (File.Exists(filename))
    {

        using (var str = new StreamWriter(filename))

        {
            str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);
            str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);
            str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);
            str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);
            str.Flush();
        }

    }

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}


}
```

Comment: What does Process Monitor show? (I suspect the "~" in the filename is not getting translated as you expect.)

Comment: What happens when you debug through? Does the `File.CreateText` line get hit?

Comment: There is something wrong here: `string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}.txt", DateTime.Now); `. Your code cannot be compiled.

Comment: You don't need the Flush call, it will be called automatically when the stream is disposed.

Comment: @Steve there is no any compilation error.How can correct it ? What is the error?

Comment: As Steve pointed out, there is an error on line `string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}.txt", DateTime.Now);`. You are using string format with two place holders ({0} and {1}) but supplying only one parameter. This will cause an exception at runtime. To fix it, add the parameter for {1}.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong saying that your code is not compilable. It compiles but if you reach that line it breaks out with a FormatException. So, if this is the code, how have you determined that the file is not written to disk?

Comment: @Steve When i run it didn't show me any error.but when i run then(pass query string to check it),then this code wont do anything.

Comment: Just to exclude this FormatException. Could you remove that {1} from the string format and see if the file is created or not?

Answer (score 5):

There is something wrong here:

```
string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}.txt", DateTime.Now); .
```

You call string.Format passing a format string that requires two parameters `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` and `{1}`, but you give only one `DateTime.Now`. When your code reaches that line raises a FormatException and jumps to the catch block exiting without writing anything to disk.

EDIT:
If you don't want to overwrite the contents of the file then you should use the overloaded constructor of StreamWriter that allows to Append to the existing file

```
.....
else if (File.Exists(filename))  
{  
    using (var str = new StreamWriter(filename, true))  
    {
         ....
```

but I think that you don't need that check on File.Exists. If you look carefully to the StreamWriter documentation you will see that the file is created when it doesn't exist. So the above code could really simplified to

```
    using (var str = new StreamWriter(path, true))      
    {      
        str.WriteLine("msisdn: " + source);      
        str.WriteLine("shortcode : " + dest);      
        str.WriteLine("Message : " + messageIn);      
        str.WriteLine("Operator :" + operatorNew);      
        str.Flush();      
    }
```

removing the unnecessary if blocks

Comment: Yes.file created.When file is not exist file created and write text.When file exist write text but Overried old text..How to solve that ?

Comment: Answer updated to show how to append text to an existing file.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void SetPartnerTemplate()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            widget.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));

            string setting = sb.ToString();

            string fileLoc = @"D:\sample1.txt";
            FileStream fs = null;
            if (!File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                using (fs = File.Create(fileLoc))
                {
                }
            }

            if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc))
                {
                    sw.Write(setting);
                }
            }
            if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                setting = File.ReadAllText(fileLoc);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('File not found');</script>");
            }
            //after writing storing dat file to db

            //VoCServiceObj.SpSetWidgetRatingPartnerTemplate(setting, partnerid, productid);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            widget.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb)));
            string setting = sb.ToString();
            string fileLoc = @"D:\Newsample.txt";
            FileStream fs = null;
            if (!File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                using (fs = File.Create(fileLoc))
                {
                }
            }
            if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc))
                {
                    sw.Write(setting);
                }
            }
            if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                setting = File.ReadAllText(fileLoc);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('File not found');</script>");
            }

            FileStream st = new FileStream(fileLoc, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[st.Length];
            st.Read(buffer, 0, (int)st.Length);

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=dsname;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=test;pwd=password");
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd1.Connection = conn;
            //OpenConnection(conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Files(Data) VALUES(@Data)", conn);


            //string commandText = "INSERT INTO Files VALUES(@Name, @ContentType, ";commandText = commandText + "@Size, @Data)";
            //cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary);

            //cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = "name";
            //cmd.Parameters["@ContentType"].Value = "contentType";
            //cmd.Parameters["@size"].Value = 5;
            cmd.Parameters["@Data"].Value = buffer;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Data from Files", conn);
            byte[] buffer3 = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();

            FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(@"D:\op.txt", FileMode.Create);
            fs2.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs2.Close();
            st.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```